# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: uuid

Tags: reactjs, react-native, uuid

[ReferenceError: Can't find variable: uuid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Inyu.jpg)

Getting this error in my react native project while using the `uuidv4` package. I am importing into my file in this way:

`import 'react-native-get-random-values';`

`import {uuid} from 'uuidv4';`

After dismissing the error, the app works fine and uuids are being generated. Error appears only right after building the app

Answer (score 1):

You may try uuid(https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) package and can use it like this:

`import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
 uuidv4();`